# How to filter QuerySet depending on fields of a reverse foreign key related model?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two following models:

```
class Tour(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=3000, blank=True

    # some other fields here
```

and

```
class TourDatesInfo(models.Model):
    departure_date = models.DateTimeField()
    return_date = models.DateTimeField()
    tour = models.ForeignKey(Tour, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dates')
```

`Tour` model has a one-to-many relationship with a `TourDatesInfo`, so that one tour may have multiple different sets of departure/return dates.

What I try to achieve is to be able to filter the tours `QuerySet` depending on their set of `TourDatesInfo`, preciesely on whether each tour contains departure/return pair that satisfies specific conditions, e.g., get all tours that have at least one `TourDatesInfo` with `departure_date` > 2022-04-12 and `return_date` < 2022-05-01.

I can write an SQL query to perform this, something like `SELECT * FROM tours_tour tours WHERE tours.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT tour_id FROM tours_tourdatesinfo WHERE departure_date > '2022-04-12' AND return_date < '2022-05-01');`, but how it can be done using django ORM without raw queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Tour.objects.filter(
    dates__departure_date__gt='2022-04-12',
    dates__return_date__lt='2022-05-01'
).distinct()
```

This will make a `JOIN` on the table of the `TourDatesInfo` model, and filter on the `departure_date` and `return_date`. If there is thus such `TourDatesInfo`, it will return the `Tour` data. The [**`.distinct()`** call <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) is used to prevent returning the same `Tour` for as many times as there are matching `TourDatesInfo`s.